# Validate Datepicker Renewal Date With Current Date and check if datepicker date is less than current date

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, datepicker

I am going to validate Entered `Renewaldate(DatePicker)` With The Current Date.But I Am in Need To Know How to Validate Date Picker Renewal Date With The Current Date And My requirement Is to Give Error Message When `DatePicker(Renewal)` Date Is Less than Current Date.So I have my code Can u Please help In giving the solutions Please....Thank you In Advance...

**member_add.php**

```
<?php
    include('assets/page_header.php');
?>           

<style>
   #display {
      color:red;
      font-size:12px;
      text-align:center;
   }
</style>    
<div class="container">
   <h1>ADDING THE MEMBER</h1>
   <form name="memadd" id="memadd" action="#" method="post">
      <table align='center'>
         <tr>
            <td> <label for="name">MemberName</label></td>
            <td ><input id="name" name="name"  type="text" /></td>                           
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td> <label for="address">Address</label></td>
            <td ><textarea id="address"></textarea></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
         <td>
            <label for="phno">phonenumber</label></td>
            <td ><input id="phno" name="phno" type="text" /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>            
            <td><label for="renewaldate">RenewalDate</label></td>
            <td ><input id="renewaldate" name="renewaldate" type="text" /> </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td> <label for="maxborrowlimit">maxborrowlimit</label></td>
            <td ><input id="maxborrowlimit" name="maxborrowlimit" type="text" />  </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td> <label for="status">Status</label></td>
            <td ><select name="status" id="status">
<option value="ACTIVE">Active</option>
<option value="INACTIVE">Inactive</option>
</select></td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" name="click" value="add" id="click">
      <div id="display"> </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**memberaddajx.php**

```
<?php
include('db.php');

//$renewaldate1 = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 
    $memname=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['memname1']);
    $address=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['address1']);
    $phonenumber=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phonenumber1']);
    $renewaldate=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['renewaldate1']);


    $maxborrowlimit=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['maxborrowlimit1']);
    $status=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['status1']);
    //$renewaldate=$renewaldate1;

    $str="insert into member(name,address,phno,renewaldate,maxborrowlimit,status) values('$memname','$address',$phonenumber,'$renewaldate',$maxborrowlimit,'$status')";
    $query1=mysql_query($str,$dbconn);
    $display=$query1;
    $query2=mysql_query("select * from member");
    $display.= $query2;
    $result1=mysql_num_rows($query2);
        if($result1>0)
        {
        $display="Data Is Entered";
        }
        else
        {
        $display="Enter data";
        }
        echo  $display;

?>
```

script.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $( "#renewaldate" ).datepicker();
$("#click").click(function(e){
    //alert("click");
    console.log("div value"+$('#display').html());
    var currentdate=new date();
    var memname = $("#name").val();
    var address = $("#address").val();
    var phonenumber = $("#phno").val();
    var renewaldate = $("#renewaldate").val();
    var d=$.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", new Date(renewaldate));
     alert(d);

    var maxborrowlimit = $("#maxborrowlimit").val();
    var status = $("#status").val();

    /*var email = $("#email").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    var contact = $("#contact").val();*/
    // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
    //var dataString = 'name1='+ name + '&email1='+ email + '&password1='+ password + '&contact1='+ contact;
    var dataString='memname1='+memname+'&address1='+address+'&phonenumber1='+phonenumber+'&renewaldate1='+d+'&maxborrowlimit1='+maxborrowlimit+'&status1='+status;
```

alert(d);
        //alert(dataString);

```
    //var dataString = $(this).serializeArray();

        if(memname==''||address==''||phonenumber==''||renewaldate==''||maxborrowlimit==''||status=='')
        {
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML="Please Fill All The Fields";
        }
        else if(!validate4(memname))
        {
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML="Please Enter Valid MemberName";
        document.getElementById("name").focus();
        }
        else if(d<currentdate)
        {
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML="Please Enter RenewalDate After t=The  Current Date";
        }
         else if(!validatephonenumber(phonenumber))
        {
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML="Please Enter Valid PhoneNumber";
        document.getElementById("phno").focus();
        }
        else if(!validate5(maxborrowlimit))
        {
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML="Please Enter Valid MaxBorrowLimit>0";
        document.getElementById("maxborrowlimit").focus();
        } else {            
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "db/memaddajax.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){
            //alert("submitted"+result);
            $('#display').html(result);
            window.location.href="members.php";                                         
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);
            }
            });             
        }

        e.preventDefault();
        });
        function validatephonenumber(phonenumber) {
        var p=phonenumber;
        var filter=/^[789]\d{9}$/;
        if(filter.test(p)) {
        return true;
        }
        else {
        return false;
        }
        }
        function validate4(memname)
        {
    var m=memname;
    var filter=/^[A-Za-z  ]+$/g;
    if(filter.test(m)) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        function validate5(maxborrowlimit) {
            var a = maxborrowlimit;
            var filter=/^[1-9][0-9]*$/;
            if(filter.test(a)) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: Please Can AnyOne Help Me

Comment: alert the  Entered Renewaldate in your js and tell me did you get it right

Comment: bro its not going to ajax page itself

Comment: Bro Its Not Going To Ajax Itself

Comment: i didnt see the part where you include the script.js file

Comment: I have Include after var d declaration in script.js

Comment: what i asked you is i didn;t see this..<script type="text/javascript" src="yoururl/ script.js"></script>

Comment: <script src="js/script.js"></script>

Comment: edit that in your question also..and do you get error messages now

Comment: This Is External js File,

Comment: that's wht i am talking..you have to include you js file like this <script type="text/javascript" src="yoururl/ script.js"></script> in the html page

Comment: When i Add It Date Picker Function Dosen't Work

Comment: I Have added type ="text/javascript" , still Its not going to ajax page